# checking whether a string contains any special character or string in javascript

Tags: javascript, alert

I want to check whether a string has any special characters or not. I am using this script:

```
var name = $("#name").val();
if(name.match(/[_\W]0-9/))
{
    alert('Not A Name');
}
```

It doesn't alert even when `name="sas23"`

Comment: for your purpose what are NOT special characters? (what characters are allowed?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead `/[_\W]0-9/` your regex literal should be `/[_\W0-9]/`

Answer (score 2):

Your function should be like this:

```
var name=$("#name").val();
if(!isLetters(name))
{
   alert('Not A Name');
}
function isLetters(str) {
   return /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always take a whitelist approach when creating regular expressions. That means specify which characters are allowed, and ban everything else by default. If all you want is letters, then only allow letters:

```
var name=$("#name").val();

if(!name.match(/^[a-z]+$/i)) {
    alert('Not A Name');
}
```

[Try it out.](http://regexr.com?33dn4)